# Burn into image dynamic Note value

Tags: objects

Put this value:
[image]

Here: [image]

Hello!  Is it possible to burn object rotation parameter (for example..) to each frame? I mean to make object rotation value dynamic in notes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy
import math

def stamp_set(scene, dummy):
    # find object for example 'CamCurve'
    obj = scene.objects.get("CamCurve")

    if obj:
        # getting obj data for example rotation
        rotation = obj.rotation_euler
        rotation_degrees = [math.degrees(angle) for angle in rotation]
        rotation_text = "Rotation: {:.2f}°, {:.2f}°, {:.2f}°".format(*rotation_degrees)
    else:
        rotation_text = "CamCurve object not found"

    # add data to stamp
    scene.render.stamp_note_text = rotation_text

bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(stamp_set)
```

Working in Blender 4.0